# Test suite failed to run ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){wOF2

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, configuration

[image]

When i try run test cases, this error is showing me.

> D:\Prince Verma\Projects\CCTV\all-web-ui-versions...\dist\fonts\inter-bold.woff2:1
> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){wOF2

I tried to map using below code in jest in package but it didnt help:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
            "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "./src/fileMock.js"
        }
```

Help me to configure jest in my react project
Test suite failed to run